# Electric pump motor wiring

Tags: electrical

I have a Franklin Electric motor, model no. 1313007142 1hp ph3 3450 rpm 230v/460hz, it has 9 black wires, numbered 1 to 9, inside the rear of motor all even number wires come out one side and all odds come out the other side, do I supply 110v to each side and ground the motor. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's a 3 phase motor, so no, you don't "apply 110V to each side" - you need a source of 3 phase power.

Answer (score 3):

You find the manual and determine how the wires are supposed to be connected up so you don't let the magic smoke out.

It's three phase, and can be supplied either Delta or Wye. How is your 3-phase circuit provided by the electric company configured? You WILL NOT BE RUNNING THIS OFF SPLIT-PHASE 120/240V house power unless you have a magic box called a phase converter which generates 3-phase power from 240V Single Phase.

Here is a 3-phase connection diagram from Franklin's AIM literature.

[image]

Unless you have a 3-phase power installation or have a Phase Converter, you will need to return the pump motor and exchange it for a 240V Single Phase capacitor start motor and wire that to run off the two hot legs for 240V single phase line input power.

If none of this makes sense, you need to consult an electrician. If this is a replacement pump for an already existing Franklin 3-phase pump, he can check to see if you have a Phase Converter already in position and make sure the connections are properly made so the pump motor doesn't get fried.

http://www.franklin-electric.com/media/documents/M1311_60_Hz_AIM_Catalog.pdf

**Note:** I realize the question states 9 wires, this is the closest I could come up with for pump related information on the Manufacturer website which was a 1-hp 3-phase submersible. I could not find the part number stated above and don't have a picture or description to tell me if this is a submersible or above ground motor. Having the proper manual is very important!!

Comment: All what you said, PLUS the frequency is listed 460 Hz (must be a typo for 60HZ) not available in residential power.

Comment: Yeah, thought it was a typo, unless it is meant to be powered by some DC to 3 phase converter in a solar power system running at 460 Hz. But 1 hp is a bit stiff for the average solar power system... Couldn't find the model number online so I couldn't verify any of the specs. Franklin, however, does make 460V 3-phase 1hp pumps, something a DIY should not be messing with!!!